# Getting HTML Body to extend with text

Tags: html

so what I'm trying to do basically is have the HTML document extend vertically as I add more text, and at the moment it's just giving me some really weird problems, such as:

1. The body won't extend downward as I add more text
2. The footer isn't displaying at all at this point
3. There are some weird symbols being inserted into the document
4. The only way I know how to position things is absolute, and I don't know if this is causing some problems (such as getting text under the "Home" image?)

Here's the jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9nYgb/

Any help is appreciated greatly, thank you!

Comment: Ooh, you shouldn't have omitted those optional start tags in the example. That will confuse a lot of people into proclaiming you have errors. Anyway, yes, absolute positioning an element will mess with the size of the parent, so if the parent must grow with the content, don't do that.

Comment: Another question. Is this XHTML or HTML5? It's best to choose one or the other and not mix them up.

Comment: And if you have a font name with a space in it, you **SHOULD** put quotes around the name. (Note: not **MUST**, as many people believe, but it is STRONGLY suggested that you do so.)

Answer (score 2):

Absolute positioning does tend to cause problems like that. Relative positioning is simple ... instead of using the top-left corner of the document as the origin for reference, the top-left corner of where the element was *supposed* to be is used as a reference. So <div style="position:relative;top:10px;"> will result in the element being 10px below where it would have been had no style information been provided.

Comment: Would you use relative positioning to layout a whole template?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you position elements absolutely, you take them out of the document flow.  This means that other elements will act as if they aren't there.  It's good for placing a modal popup div on top of a page, but it's not good for laying out a whole page.

In general, when it comes to laying out a page, I try to stick to a series of divs with height and width set.  You can use margin and padding to adjust layout, and float to make items stack up horizontally to one side or the other.  Sometimes I also need to set a div's display to inline or inline-block to get them to appear next to one another and act like inline elements.  You can also place divs within divs to group elements together and treat them as one by manipulating the outer container(s).

In general I don't find much need for absolute positioning in a page layout.

Comment: Would relative positioning be better for laying out a page?

Comment: I don't use it much either - only if I need to "bump" something out of it's position in some direction.  It's easier to deal with - I believe it's still part of the flow.  I mostly use position relative for other reasons, like setting z-index.

Comment: Thanks, any resources you can show me that can give me some easy knowledge on how I can best layout this site to flow?  Also, nobody seems to be touching on the other, main question - how I would get the body to extend with text - or is that something that will be fixed after I get rid of absolute?  Thanks.

Comment: I believe that will fix it - give it a shot.